# Text in h1 tag overflowing div container

Tags: html, css

The text in the h1 tag is overflowing the div container when I shrink it to view in tablet or mobile mode.Can someone please help me out with it.
[This is how it looks in regular windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCJZm.png)

[This is what happens when I shrink the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41w8a.png)

Here's the code!

```css
.chicken {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.chickenh {
  background-color: hotpink;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  left: 260px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.chicken-info {
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="chicken">
    <h1 class="chickenh">
      CHICKEN
    </h1>

    <p class="chicken-info">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: because you've given `width: 30%` in `.chicken` class

Comment: What is your desired result

Comment: Fix your `left: 260px;` in mobile version, it is causing your `<h1>` to move right in smaller viewport.

Comment: @decpk I want the text in the h1 tag which is 'Chicken' to move along with the div tag when I shrink the window.

Comment: @Snigdha ok check the answer and tell, Is this what you want

Comment: If you want to make changes in mobile or tablet mode, you can use `@media`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one way to do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
       
    .chicken{
    width:30%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    padding: 10px;
    border:3px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
}


.chickenh{
    background-color: hotpink;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin: -13px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    border: 3px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: right;
    
}


.chicken-info{
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="chicken">
        <h1 class="chickenh">
            CHICKEN
        </h1>
    
        <p class="chicken-info">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </p>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's great the code works, but an explanation would be nice, like what part of code you have changed to achieve this.

Comment: the problem was with the `left:260px ` on chicken element it meant it should always be 260px apart from the left side of the parent element and when you shrink your element the width of it will be lower than 260px so it going to overflow I removed that part and replace it with `float: left` and then because of how float works I added a `float: right` to the chicken-info class. I would be appreciated it if you mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

### Be aware that below answer is assumed you want `.chicken` `width: 30%`. If you don't want then make it `width: 100%`

Just remove the `left:260px` and add `width: 100%` and `text-align:center`;

```css
.chicken {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.chickenh {
  background-color: hotpink;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.chicken-info {
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="chicken">
  <h1 class="chickenh">
    CHICKEN
  </h1>
  <p class="chicken-info">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
</div>
```

If you don't want `width: 30%` then check as follows

```css
.chicken {
  float: left;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.chickenh {
  background-color: hotpink;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.chicken-info {
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="chicken">
  <h1 class="chickenh">
    CHICKEN
  </h1>
  <p class="chicken-info">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
</div>
```